# Randomly graphql error "field 'apellido' not found in type: 'profesores'"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, graphql, hasura

I'm working with a React App, using Heroku and Hasura.

After creating the column "apellido" in my table "profesor" in Hasura, i have been getting randomly this error whenever i'm trying to retrieve the "apellido" data from "profesor"

```
field 'apellido' not found in type: 'profesores'"
```

in, for example, this subscription.

```
subscription GetProfesor2($profesorKey: uuid!) {
                profesores(where: { key: { _eq: $profesorKey } }) {
                    key
                    nombre
                                        apellido
                    editor
                }
            }
```

For some reason, my react SPA sometimes throws this error, getting stuck randomly because of it.

If i spam f5, sometimes it works and i'm able to navigate and do stuff, but if i reload again or change users, there's a chance for the error to appear and i'm forced to just spam f5 until it dissapears.

I tried to run yarn-codegen after creating the column "apellido" in my table before uploading the code, "reload" the metadata in hasura and trying to find if there's a setup in hasura but was unable to find anything. [[image: hasura]]

Sorry about the info but i'm a novice at this so it's hard to know what or where i should look.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue, when you're getting that error can you check if your JWT token is being sent correctly?

Comment: Does it make sense? A few months ago a ex co-worker added the same colum to another user type, and a few weeks ago i was able to update those subscriptions/query with no problem.
Unfortunately it only happened in prod so in my haste I was forced to revert those subscriptions/queries for now.

I'll try to find the JWT token to see if it's getting the info correctly, but it's strange that it's not a 100% failure rate. Thanks!

Comment: very strange that it's not 100% failure. this does sound like a potential JWT issue—but iirc an expired token would result in a different error. my guess is that your JWT is not consistently setting the correct `role` for your user?